# index is outside the bounds of array

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

My try/catch expression always gives me a error message that "index is outside the bounds of array" however the function is working perfectly the way it should work. The only problem is that annoying mistake.

this is the code I'm using:

```
        Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim Qwery As String = "SELECT a.accid AS 'No', a.setID AS 'ID', l.class AS 'Type', CONCAT(fname,' ',middname,' ',lname ) AS 'Name', date(a.bdate) AS 'BirthDate', l.mail AS 'Acount Name', l.login AS 'Login',  l.gender AS 'Gender', l.position AS 'Position', l.department AS 'Department',  l.tel AS 'Tel No', l.localno AS 'Office Tel', l.cellno AS 'Cell Phone', l.alt_email AS 'Other Email', l.classif AS 'Classification', l.status AS 'Status' FROM entry a, liist l WHERE a.accid = l.accid AND l.status = '0' ORDER BY a.accid Desc"

        Dim smd As MySqlCommand
        Dim myreader As MySqlDataReader
        smd = New MySqlCommand(Qwery, myconn)
        myreader = smd.ExecuteReader
        If myreader.Read() = True Then
            IdBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(0)
            IdNumBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(1)
            TypeBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(2)
            NameBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(3)
            BDayBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(4)
            AcNameBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(5)
            PassBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(6)
            GenBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(7)
            PositionBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(8)
            DepartmentBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(9)
            TelBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(10)
            OfficeBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(11)
            CellBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(12)
            altMailBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(13)
            ClassBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(14)
            StatusBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(15)
        End If

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message.ToString())
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

The interesting point that I tried removing assignments of labels one by one. And up to `myreader.GetValue(3)` the error does not appear. If I try assigning more lables it appears again.

Does anyone know the reason behind?

Comment: check your Datareader properly.u fetching data from beyond the index

Comment: Check the n° of columns myreader() is returning. I bet its less than 15!

Comment: what do you mean by checking datareader? can you elaborate please?

Comment: if it less then 15 how come the output is perfectly correct?

Comment: as I mention output works normally. all 15 lables are filled. Only this annoying error pumps up.

Comment: How many columns are you retrieving through your data reader?

Comment: I'm retreaving 15 and there are 16. I've checked it

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with the debugger line by line?  What line does the exception indicate is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition for the datareader has greater than 15 rows.then access your code .

```
myreader = smd.ExecuteReader
        If myreader.Read() = True Then
if myreader.GetSchemaTable().Rows.Count >= 15 then
            IdBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(0)
            IdNumBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(1)
            TypeBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(2)
            NameBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(3)
            BDayBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(4)
            AcNameBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(5)
            PassBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(6)
            GenBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(7)
            PositionBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(8)
            DepartmentBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(9)
            TelBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(10)
            OfficeBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(11)
            CellBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(12)
            altMailBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(13)
            ClassBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(14)
            StatusBox.Text = myreader.GetValue(15)
        End If
 End If
```

or try `datareaderObject.RecordsAffected >= 15`

Comment: I tried `myreader.FieldCount()` instead because `myreader.GetSchemaTable().Rows` gives me a mistake

Comment: Yes , Fieldcount is not bad ! and  if that not worked , try "Recored Affected " option !!

Comment: And try myreader.GetSchemaTable().Rows to myreader.GetSchemaTable().Rows.Count

Comment: I tried `Dim Pomp As Integer = myreader.FieldCount() MsgBox(Pomp)` The result is 16. its pretty much enough for 15 and shouldn't be out of index

Answer (score 0):

i think in your query date(a.bdate) AS 'BirthDate' is throwing the error

may be the reason is that a.bdate is null value and can not be converted into date..